# I try Darknet-On-OpenCL project, can pass building,but error notify "couldn't open file: cfg/coco.data"

Tags: yolo, darknet

I try Darknet-On-OpenCL project, can pass building,but error notify "couldn't open file: cfg/coco.data".
The project is be in https://github.com/ganyc717/Darknet-On-OpenCL/issues
I can find the cfg/coco.data, but I do not know why could be opened.
How should I do ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should also check whether the cfg/coco.data exists in your cfg folder or not. If no, try to create it. It should have 80 labels
The detect command is shorthand for a more general version of the command. It is equivalent to the command:

`./darknet detector test cfg/coco.data cfg/yolov3.cfg yolov3.weights data/dog.jpg`

Therefore, you can add the data path in another to detect scheme by this way